# remove parameters from Facebook authentication redirect

Tags: php, facebook

I use the PHP SDK and follow the example. https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk

When I log in with Facebook and grant access, the page will redirect to my current page, but the url contains `state` and `code`. How to avoid displaying these parameters?

code is as follows:

```
"oauth.php":
<?php
require 'sdk/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(XXX,XXX));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
}
?>

+++++++++++++++++++
"index.php":

<?php include 'oauth.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div>
  <?php if ($user): ?>
    <img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user; ?>/picture">
  <?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
  <?php endif ?>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding a header at the end of the code (after authentication)

```
   header('Location:'.$currentPage);
```

Comment: How do you get `$currentPage`? Where do you put this line?

Comment: $currentPage is the page that facebook redirects back to, or $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']. Place this line at the end in that page where facebook redirects back, of course only after successful authentication

Comment: Just use `Facebook::getCurrentUrl()` – that method is designed to strip the Facebook-specific parameters (state, code, …) from the current page’s URL, while leaving any URL parameters of your own that might be in there intact (as long as there are no name collisions). It returns a “cleaned” URL that you can redirect to.